# May I use participle clause about "one action that happens just before another" in simple tense?

Tags: american-english, participle-clauses

My own example:

> "I take off my contact lenses and I always feel tingle."

Does the sentence I shortened equal the example below?

> "Taking off my contact lenses, I always feel tingle."

Comment: _When taking out my contact lenses, I always feel a tingle._  You take **out** a contact lens, not "off".

Comment: "While" works just as well, but it's not "one action happens just before another", it's *simultaneous*.

Comment: They seem about the same to me, however, you should either say "feel **a** tingle," or "feel tingle**s**."

Answer (score 1):

No, it gets interpreted as "simultaneous action" rather than one that follows the other.

I think the problem is that "taking [out]" is a continuous action, not a complete one.  You could say

> *Finishing* taking out my contact lenses, I always feel ...

The use of the "*finishing*" gives the previous action (taking out of lenses) completeness, which helps in temporal and causal connection to the next action, feeling the tingle.

Or, simpler,

> **After** taking out my contact lenses, I always feel ...